# Table relationship in hive, Spark Sql and Azure USQL

Tags: azure, hive, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way i can maintain table relationship in Hive, Spark SQL and Azure U SQL. Does any of these support creating relationships like in Oracle or SQL Server. In oracle i can get the relationships using user_constraints table. Looking for something similar to that for processing in ML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe any of the big data platforms support integrity constraints. They are designed to load data as quickly as possible. Having constraints will only slow down the import. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

None of the big data tools maintain constraints. If we just consider hive it doesn't even bother while you are writing data to the table whether the table schema is maintained or not as Hive follows schema on read approach.
While reading the data if you want to establish any relation, one has to work with joins.